# How can I setup the environment of an integrated VS Code terminal depending on the active CMake configuration preset?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say I have 2 configuration presets, CMakePresets.json:

```
    "configurePresets": [
      {
        "name": "EnvA",
        "description": "Using A ..."
      },
      {
        "name": "EnvB",
        "description": "Using B ... "
      }
    ]
```

I want to run the integrated terminal with some custom scripts or to set the environment of the terminal depending on the configuration, settings.json:

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Command Prompt": {
        "path": [ "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe" ],
        "args": [ "/k", "<path>/setup.sh" ],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
  "terminal.integrated.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

So, the idea is ether to run conditionally somehow a different script `setupA.sh` or `setupB.sh` or somehow to set the environment variables for the terminal's environment to have something like this `"args": [ "/k", "<path>/setup.sh ${env:VSCODE_PRESET}" ],`.

I tried setting variables in the preset:

```
      {
        "name": "EnvA",
        "description": "Using A ...",
        "cacheVariables": { "VSCODE_PRESET": "${presetName}" },
        "environment": { "VSCODE_PRESET": "${presetName}" }
      },
```

But then I cannot see them in (or don't know how to transfer those to) the terminal's environment.

I also tried to set the terminal's environment variable, like so:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": { "VSCODE_PRESET": "${presetName}" }
```

but `${presetName}` is not accessible from `settings.json`.

Is there any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

The `environment` property of the configure preset is for CMake when it runs configuration.

Note that there is no CMake Tools-contributed VS Code variable named `presetName`. There is `cmake.activeConfigurePresetName`. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#variable-substitution. It won't affect integrated terminals of VS Code.

Most VS Code variables are not supported in settings.json. This is essentially stated in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_is-variable-substitution-supported-in-user-and-workspace-settings. See also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2809.

So my thought is no, I'm not aware of how to get what you want. And I'd be curious to know what you're actually trying to achieve. This might be an XY problem.

From [our conversation in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254979/room-for-starball-and-alex), you further clarified:

> the script doesn't do anything for the the vscode build system per say... it initializes the environment to help working with the specific board, flashing, etc...

In this case, it's a plus if you can find a way to get your IDE to help you out with setting up terminal environments,
but there may be a hidden assumption you're making that users of your project will be using specific IDEs and their integrated terminals, when they may just want to use some other terminal of their own choice, in which case you will pretty much *have to* give instructions in your user documentation that you have a environment setup script that they should run to get some goodies.

Comment: The underlining problem is what I discribed. I have 2 configuration presets (simplified): msvc-x64-debug and esp-idf. When I run the integrated terminal (cmd in my case) I need to execute an environment script if esp-idf preset is selected and do nothing if msvc! Right now I solve this issue by creating a custom terminal that has the script executed. But in this case whoever is using the library will have to know that integrated teminal woun't do... they will have to run a special custom terminal otherwise nothing is gonna build for esp target!

Comment: continuing discussion in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254979/room-for-starball-and-alex